# hide X and Y axes on charts with n3-line-chart

Tags: d3.js, charts, n3-charts

Is it possible to hide X and Y axes on a chart with n3-line-chart? I want to move from this

[image]

to this

[image]

I took a look to the [main page](http://n3-charts.github.io/line-chart/#/) but I didn't found my answer. I tried not to specify the axes but they are still visible. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Try to manage with CSS, using .x.axis{ display: none;} and for y axis .y.axis { display: none; }

Comment: Any native construct? Anyway, it works, you can put this comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to set add `mode="thumbnail"` attribute to `<linechart>` element.